# Unexpected T_STRING error in a select statement?

Tags: php, sql, select

I have an oracle connection string above the following select statement.

Here's the select statement:

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn1, 'SELECT s.SID, USERNAME AS "User", PROGRAM, MODULE,
ACTION, LOGON_TIME "Logon", l.*
FROM V$SESSION s, V$ENQUEUE_LOCK l
WHERE l.SID = s.SID
AND l.TYPE = 'CF'
AND l.ID1 = 0
AND l.ID2 = 2');

oci_execute ($stid);
```

However, it's giving me a t_string error on line 69. Which is this line:

```
AND l.TYPE = 'CF'
```

Is the single quotes the issue?

Comment: Yes.  You have single quotes inside your single quotes.  Escape them `l.TYPE = \'CF\'` or use double quotes `l.TYPE = "CF"`.

Comment: The color of your code should have been helped you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the single quotes:

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn1, 'SELECT s.SID, USERNAME AS "User", PROGRAM, MODULE,
ACTION, LOGON_TIME "Logon", l.*
FROM V$SESSION s, V$ENQUEUE_LOCK l
WHERE l.SID = s.SID
AND l.TYPE = \'CF\'
AND l.ID1 = 0
AND l.ID2 = 2')
```

Right  now, it's being parsed as:

```
'SELECT s.SID, USERNAME AS "User", PROGRAM, MODULE,
 ACTION, LOGON_TIME "Logon", l.*
 FROM V$SESSION s, V$ENQUEUE_LOCK l
 WHERE l.SID = s.SID
 AND l.TYPE = '
```

And then your value, and then another string, which is invalid syntax.

Comment: Or use double quotes `l.TYPE = "CF"`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the single quotes are the issue.

Either escape the CF quotes like this `\'CF\'` or use " instead.